# Webpack showing warnings that are no longer relevant - Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I recently updated to Material UI5 and had to make a whole bunch of changes in the codebase. I did a lot of this using the VSCode search and replace function.

Now, whenever I build my app, I get a whole string of warnings saying that there is an unused import, even though all of these lines have been removed. (Note: This is all on the dev build)

If I go into the file that is generating the warning and save it (even though there are no changes to be saved) then it seems that webpack recognizes the change and stops issuing the warning.

Is there any way to somehow clear the cache or get webpack to recognize that these warnings aren't current?

File:
[image: tags-list-button.tsx]

Warning:
[image: warning about tags-list-button.tsx]

edit: `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks', '@typescript-eslint', 'cypress'],
  rules: {
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error', // Checks rules of Hooks
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn', // Checks effect dependencies
    'no-use-before-define': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-namespace': ['off'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': ['off'], // Maybe a good rule, but it's a pain in the ass
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    },
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    // 'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.jsx'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/recommended': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
      },
    },
    {
      files: ['**/styles.ts'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you share your eslint config and also first try removing `package-lock.json` and `node_module` and reinstall all packages.

Comment: Added the config. Deleting package-lock.json seems a bit heavy handed don't you think? I'd rather not do that.

Comment: React MUI5 has drastic changes and I am assuming maybe default package-lock might not have handled that well. You could backup your package-lock and try if this fixes. Depends on your use case. Might wanna elaborate a bit on what you mean by heavy-handed, perhaps I still don't understand the package-lock file?

Comment: I'm also getting this - my dev build is warning me about lines that are long gone. There's evidently some kind of cache that webpack is using. Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: I somehow did solve it, yes, however I can't exactly remember how. When I look back at the PR I can see that my package-lock.json had quite a few changes, so it could be that the deletion solution actually helped. I have since updated many other things so I can't really help based on the current state of the project.